# Animating Map Height Performance Issues

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am working on creating a reactive UI using a map and menu at the bottom. My map is using the builtin windows phone bing maps control with a user control below it.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Controls:Map x:Name="map"/>
    <Border Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"
            Grid.Row="1">
        <telerikPrimitives:RadTransitionControl Grid.Row="1">
            <views:OverviewPage/>
        </telerikPrimitives:RadTransitionControl>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

And my animation looks like this. I've drawn out the time for a longer period of time to show the issues.

```
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation() { Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), To = 480, From = 0 };

Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, map);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(HeightProperty));

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
storyboard.Begin();
```

Now, if I swap out my Map control for something else, say a Border. Everything works as you would expect, the animation is smooth. The issue is my UI updates only every half second or so if I use the map. I'm getting this lag on a Lumia 1520, I can't imagine how bad it is on a lower end device.

I am looking for some way to improve the performance of this animation or some alternative. Has anyone tried this before or do you know a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is that every time the map is moved, or resized there is a bunch of calculations that have to be done by the map. When you animate the map, the size of the map updates a bunch of times in a very short time, causing the map to recalculate everything a bunch of times. Map controls in general tend to be heavy weight controls due to all the data and calculations involved. Things like animating the map size should be avoided, especially on less powerful devices, such as mobile phones.

Comment: I've played with this a bit more and it is as you suggest. I'll need to come up with some other way to produce this. I'd note also that this is not limited to the Map control but can be produced with a Web Browser or any other graphically intense User Control.